# Facebook mbasic site, mobile safari, home screen shortcuts and local storage

Tags: html, ios, facebook, safari, storage

I have a question about the mbasic.facebook.com page and how they manage to do what they do on iPhone with iOS 12.3.1. This is not about the facebook app. I don't have it installed at all.

I went to mbasic.facebook.com in mobile safari on iOS and created a shortcut for it on my homescreen. When I use the shortcut, the page behaves like what Apple calls a [web application](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html), i.e. it does not have the usual mobile safari UI.

Here's the weird part:

After using the shortcut and logging in, I switch to the settings app and under "Safari", I delete the browser history and website data.

I then use the shortcut again to launch the mbasic facebook site.

I am greeted with a screen where I still appear to be logged in. If i interact with the page it will make me login again, however.

This makes me wonder about two things:

1. How does the web application maintain its state (i.e. still know who am i) despite me trying to delete the Safari data?
2. How do I delete the data in a way that also affects a "web app" launched via a home screen shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly. But I think it was done by PWA(Progressive Web App) technology. It helps you to use a website as an app that are installed from app store. And it also has the ability of state maintaining, giving push notification, maintain own storage in your device. When you installed it, all your login information was saved in your device as its own storage and this storage has no relation with your web browser. That;s why when you delete data from Safari, it made no effects on the installed one. 
And when you installed it, it installed its own manifest file in your device. That's why it runs on your device with it's own UI not with the safari UI. 
You can delete its data by deleting its storage folder that is created at the time of installation. I am not sure where you got the file in your device. 
Make a research on it. Here are some useful link about PWA. 
 [MDN web docs - PWA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps)  
 [4 important points to know about Progressive Web Apps (PWA)](https://medium.com/@deepusnath/4-points-to-keep-in-mind-before-introducing-progressive-web-apps-pwa-to-your-team-8dc66bcf6011) 
 [PWA Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gTxqJBcDmoi5Q2pzDusSL7) 
Hope it will help you. You are requested to share any new thing that should be known as I am new in this technology.